# How to keep centered 3 divs vertically in responsive mode (mobile vs desktop)

Tags: html, css, alignment, containers, css-float

When I try to do the responsive mode, adjusting the 3 div 
from horizontal to vertical, they don't align vertically and centered.

Here you can see my code; https://codepen.io/josemb94/pen/bXaeYp

```
<center>
  <div id="container">
                <div id="left">
                    <h2>11111</h2>
                </div>
                <div id="right">
                    <h2>333333</h2>
                </div>
                <div id="center">
                    <h2>22222</h2>
                </div>
  </div>
</center>

 #container {
            width: 57.5%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #left {
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            height: 120px;
            border-style: solid;
        }

        #center {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 200px;
            height: 120px;
            border-style: solid;
        }

        #right {
            float: right;
            width: 200px;
            height: 120px;
            border-style: solid;
        }
```

I tried 3 or 4 css styles but any works...

My result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYkNn.png

My expect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyrdx.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of floating your `#left` and `#right` elements, instead give them `display: block` and a `margin` of `0 auto`:

```css
#container {
  width: 57.5%;
  text-align: center;
}

#left {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#center {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#right {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <h2>11111</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <h2>333333</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="center">
    <h2>22222</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now all three of your child elements have the same styles, so you can simply the CSS as follows:

```css
#container {
  width: 57.5%;
  text-align: center;
}

#left, #center, #right {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <h2>11111</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <h2>333333</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="center">
    <h2>22222</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

And you can simplify this even further with the **[child combinator selector (`>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)**, eliminating the need for any IDs or classes on the HTML elements:

```css
#container {
  width: 57.5%;
  text-align: center;
}

#container > div {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <h2>11111</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>333333</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>22222</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the `<center>` tag is **[not supported in HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)**, so I have removed it in the above examples.

Also note that you could opt for `display: inline-block` instead, which would allow the elements to sit next to one another, provided there is enough `width` in the `#container` to contain them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `grid` layout and set the column template in a media query depending on your requirement.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  border-style: solid;
  justify-self: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left" class="item">
    <h2>11111</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="item">
    <h2>333333</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="center" class="item">
    <h2>22222</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```